# How to use AWS CLI in PowerShell to update values in DynamoDB containing a whitespace?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I've been fiddling for a while with updating records in DynamoDB using the AWS CLI from PowerShell. I can't seem to update a value that contains a whitespace. See below command where 2021-11-17 14:48:41 contains the whitespace. I've tried a lot of different quote and escape combinations, but haven't been successful. Any help would be appreciated.

This is from a Windows 2016 server running AWS CLI 1.18.216. In bash or PowerShell Core on MacOS I don't experience this issue.

Command:

```
aws dynamodb update-item `
    --table-name $TableName `
    --key $KeyStackJson `
    --update-expression 'SET #H = :h,#D = :d,#E = :e' `
    --expression-attribute-names $AttributeNameJson `
    --expression-attribute-values '{\":h\":{\"S\":\"0.0.189-alpha\"},\":d\":{\"S\":\"test\"},\":e\":{\"S\":\"2021-11-17 14:48:41\"}}'
```

Output:

```
Unknown options: 14:48:41"}}
```

Comment: Generally, Windows doesn't deal well with single quotes in my experience. Given that you've quoted all the inner double quotes, did you try simply replacing the outer single quotes with double quotes?

Comment: @jarmod that didn't work out, but will solve it in a different way. Will store it with ISO 8601 formatting and after pulling from Dynamo, change it for display.

Comment: The interaction between PowerShell and the awscli is strange. If you use `--key '{"id": 1}'` then DynamoDB actually sees `{id: 1}` (with unquoted `id`). But when you `echo '{"id": 1}'` you get `{"id": 1}`. BTW you know there is a PowerShell-specific AWS cli, yes? Called AWS Tools for PowerShell.

Comment: Super, thanks for the help @jarmod

Answer (score 0):

To escape double quotes in powershell use following `". Example:

```
"{\`"id\`":{\`"S\`":\`"1ec9b5bb-e271-4c40-bccd-045c9d26434e\`"}}"
```

produces following string for DynamoDB

```
"{"id":{"S":"1ec9b5bb-e271-4c40-bccd-045c9d26434e"}}"
```